# Calculating round-trip propagation delay for sending data frames over a network

Tags: network-protocols, bandwidth, sliding-window, propagation

The following example is from Tanenbaum's *Computer Networks*(5th edition, page 232) and it has me confused:

> Until now we have made the tacit assumption that the transmission time required for a frame to arrive at the receiver plus the transmission time for the acknowledgement to come back is negligible. Sometimes this assumption is clearly
> false. In these situations the long round-trip time can have important implications
> for the efficiency of the bandwidth utilization. As an example, consider a 50-kbps
> satellite channel with a 500-msec round-trip propagation delay. Let us imagine
> trying to use protocol 4 to send 1000-bit frames via the satellite. At t = 0 the
> sender starts sending the first frame. At t = 20 msec the frame has been completely sent. Not until t = 270 msec has the frame fully arrived at the receiver,
> and not until t = 520 msec has the acknowledgement arrived back at the sender,
> under the best of circumstances (of no waiting in the receiver and a short acknowledgement frame). This means that the sender was blocked 500/520 or 96%
> of the time. In other words, only 4% of the available bandwidth was used. Clearly, the combination of a long transit time, high bandwidth, and short frame length
> is disastrous in terms of efficiency.

As I understand it, the time to for the sender's frame to be fully sent, or "in flight", is 20 milliseconds, and this value is arrived at by calculating the bandwidth delay product of sending a 1000-bit frame over a channel whose bandwidth equals 50kbps. So far so good. Then, the time for the frame to fully arrive at the receiver is 270 milliseconds, and this value is calculated simply by adding the one-way propagation delay, which is 250 milliseconds, to our bandwidth delay product of 20 milliseconds. How then, is it possible for the receiver's acknowledgement frame to arrive back at the sender at time t = 520 milliseconds? This seems to imply that it only took 250 milliseconds in total for the ACK frame to be fully sent and then have it arrive at the sender, completely ignoring the bandwidth delay time to get a 1000-bit frame "in-flight". The only reason I can think of to ignore the bandwidth delay time to send the ACK frame is that the receiver is not sending a whole frame, but just a single bit signaling the sequence number. Even then, the BD product for a single bit is still a non-zero value, 20 microseconds to be exact. So, in this scenario the ACK frame should arrive at the sender at time t = 520.02 milliseconds. Was this all just a typo? If not, could somebody please explain the reason for the discrepancy in calculating the times?

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, the time to for the sender's frame to be fully sent, or "in flight", is 20 milliseconds, and this value is arrived at by calculating the bandwidth delay product of sending a 1000-bit frame over a channel whose bandwidth equals 50kbps.

Not exactly. You're confusing transmission ("send") time and propagation ("in flight") time.
It takes the transmitter 20ms to send ("put") the entire packet into the air. Meaning that the last bit of the packet is sent at t=20ms. However, that's only that start of that bit's journey. It must now propagate ("fly") to the satellite, which is 250ms away. This is why the satellite received the whole packet only at t=270ms.

In other words, if we just look at the last bit of the packet, it took it 20ms to reach the air next to the transmitter, and another 250ms to reach the satellite itself.

Once the satellite receives the last bit of the packet at t=270ms, it immediately sends an ack, which is small so its transmission time is negligible. It takes that ack another 250ms (until t=520ms) to reach the ground station.